# Replacement for includeStaticTypoScriptSourcesAtEnd for TYPO3 v13+

Tags: typo3

I use `includeStaticTypoScriptSourcesAtEnd` hook which came with the `TemplateService` class to create all my TYPO3 frameworks. What it does is, it loads TypoScripts dynamically for the site (one for the whole site and another as theme for particular page hierarchies depending on the setting on the page, through a `TemplateService` hook.

The `TemplateService` is discontinued with no further information in `TYPO3` version 13. It is of immense importance. What is its new implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be able to use the Event "AfterTemplatesHaveBeenDeterminedEvent" instead. It is not an 1:1 replacement for your hook but another one. It should let you fake the `sys_template` rows that would include your files.

Documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/Events/Core/TypoScript/AfterTemplatesHaveBeenDeterminedEvent.html